# How to resize pdf graphics produced in R using Illustrator

Tags: r, pdf, adobe-illustrator

I am making plots in R using the `pdf()` command. Graphs look perfect and resize nicely in Acrobat Reader. My usual workflow includes manipulating labels etc. in Illustrator, saving as `.eps` for submission to publishers or inserting in Word. All works fine for single graphs.

Now I am trying to combine 4 graphs into one by manually putting them together in an A4 Illustrator document. However, when I resize the standard 7x7 inches pdf graph in Illustrator to fit in one column of an A4 page (ca 3.4 inches wide), all proportions get screwed up, e.g. lines and symbols outlines become way too thick. Using `pdf(..., width=3.4, height=3.4)` in R messes up all the symbol and font sizes so carefully chosen to produce the original graph. Why can't I resize the graph within Illustrator the same way I can resize the pdf e.g. in Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator is scaling *everything* including the stroke thickness, used to draw lines and symbols that have been converted to paths, and the font size for any text not converted to a path. (As I don't have Illustrator I can't say whether Illustrator treats "text" as text or as paths when opening the pdf.)

When Adobe Acrobat Reader displays the pdf it is just showing a rasterised view of the current file so just scales everything nicely as you wish.

I see two options; Either create the 2x2 plot directly in R and export that to PDF with the correct dimensions, or reduce the margins and font size used in each plot and export then at the desired width/height using the command you showed.

The first options can be achieved via:

```
pdf("attempt1.pdf", ....)
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)) ## byrow = TRUE for fill-by-row
## all 4 plot calls go in here
layout(1)
dev.off()
```

You may need to tweak the point size used in the `pdf()` device and somewhat adjust the `cex.???` settings for some bits of the plot to tailor this exactly how you want it.

Alternatively, you need to reduce the pointsize and margins and draw each plot on the 3.4 by 3.4 inch device. Something like this will get you started:

```
pdf("attempt2.pdf", height = 3.4, width = 3.4, pointsize = 10)
op <- par(mar = c(4,3,3,1) + 0.1) ## one line less per marging
## your single plotting call here
par(op)
dev.off()
```

See `?par` for the list of ways to control the plot margins & other parameters you might wish to set to control the quality of the final plot. You may wish to look into the `cex.foo` parameters to control the relative sizing of the text on the plots, but this is all relative to the base pointsize you set when you create the `pdf()` device.